# Bearer token authentication failed on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, get, client, bearer-token

i am trying to make a GET request on a web api. I build the client side. The problem seems to be on the authentication with bearer token. I've already seen a lot of posts but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AuthUsingBearerToken
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunClient();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RunClient()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri");//address of web api
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();//removes all entries from system.net.http.headers...
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//adds an entry to system in json format

            //First Method i tried
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer ", "token from web api));

            //Second method
            // var token = "token from web api";
            // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            //Third Method
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            GetPatient(client, "1").Wait();

        }
    }

    public static async Task GetPatient(HttpClient client, string id)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(""+id);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Patient patient = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Patient>();

            Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}\tName: {1}", patient.id, patient.patient_name);

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }


}
```

My problem is this:
[image]

How can i make a Bearer with token authentication?
Or is it somethimg else that i do not do correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to POST a valid request to your web api authorization endpoint (eg. "`\token`") with the following http body key value pairs : `username, password, client_id and grant_type=password`. (make sure to follow the Content-Type of your request's header)

for that use  `await client.PostAsync("token", content);`

if the authorization succeeded, you will receive a response with access_token in it. You could use a Token object to deserialize to (`ApiToken = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Add that token in your header of any subsequent request that need to be authenticated  : Authorization : Bearer {acces_token_value}

`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ApiToken.ToString());`

There is a lot of resources on that topic, the most interesting for me was :
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/